# MongoDb in Java to find users

Tags: java, mongodb, database

I have these three users in my DB with the following keys:

Jon-111

Jon-222

Jon-333

The code I wrote currently can only find one user in the DB by his key.
How can I return all these users?

```
public void getMongoDB() {

    DB db = mongo.getDB("people");
    DBCollection table = db.getCollection("users");

    BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    searchQuery.put("key", "Jon-111"); // what do I do here to return all the 'Jon' users?

    DBCursor cursor = table.find(searchQuery);

    int dbSize = cursor.size(); // size is 1
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        logger.debug(""+cursor.next()+"\n");
    }       
    logger.debug("users table");

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be something along the lines of `"key","LIKE jon-*'`. However I've never used MongoDb. So it may depend upon MongoDb specifics.

Comment: @MikeT that's a very standard SQL way to do it, but with Java/Mongo, it's slightly more complex, requiring regex, see my answer below for some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your search to be 'Starts with Jon', try:

```
 searchQuery.put("key", java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("^Jon"));
```

You will need to use regex to do this kind of query, as shown in my example.

Some more examples for your benefit:

'Ends with Jon':

```
searchQuery.put("key", java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("Jon$"));
```

'Contains Jon':

```
searchQuery.put("key", java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(".*Jon.*"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex Pattern to pass in the value.  Something like below:

```
searchQuery.put("key", java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("Jon-\\.*"));
```